# I do not see the text in 'Chiller' font, I request while using google web fonts

Tags: html, fonts, google-api

I was trying to use google web fonts on my JSP page but it doesn't seem to work correctly. On my *Fedora 16 OS* I have got `Chiller` font installed. And when I run the code that displays the text in `Chiller` font using google font apis on Fedora, it displays the text in that font but when I try it on *Ubuntu*, that doesn't have the chiller font installed, browser displays the default font it might use in the fallback. What could be the reason for this ? The snippet :

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chiller">
    <style>
        #page_font {
            font-family: 'Chiller';
            font-size: 50px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>New Year Countdown </title>

</head>

<body> <div id="page_font"> <br /> Countdown </div>  </body>
```

*Note: [The web address of that JSP page, where I have used this snippet](http://programworks.appspot.com/nyblast.jsp).*

Comment: -1 For not even checking the most basic error source by yourself. If  get a 404 when trying to load the font, the error becomes obvious.

Comment: @feeela sorry. I didn't even think of checking it.

Comment: Use a code inspector like Chrome's developer tools or Firebug for Firefox or Opera's Dragonfly. Using those tools you would immediately recognize the red lines in the network tab for those resources that couldn't be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chiller the Google website responds with:

```
Error (400): Missing font family
```

They didn't have a font named "Chiller"!

Comment: but then how does it show the chiller font on my fedora machine ?

Comment: The Chiller font is installed in some systems. It must not be distributed or used as a web font; if you try to process it at FontSquirrel, you will see the message “ITC has requested that their font Chiller Regular be blacklisted by the Generator. You will not be able to convert this font.” So it’s no wonder that Google hasn’t got it.

Comment: @Suhail Gupta …which also means, that you are trying to use a font without a proper license to do so. I can't imagine that this would be legal (not even in India).

Comment: @feeela I really didn't know one could use a font after only purchasing a license.

Comment: @Suhail Gupta Well copyright isn't a new thing. There are copyright restrictions in nearly any country on this planet. See [Copyright](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright) or [प्रतिलिप्यधिकार](http://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/प्रतिलिप्यधिकार)